# how to separate number using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, separator, digit-separator

I have a quetion please help me.
I have number 21 or 22 or 23 etc.
and I want to separate that number to be 20 and 1 or 20 and 2 or 20 and 3 etc.
how to make it programmaticly in javascript. Sorry before cause I really confused and dont know the keyword to search on internet.
Thanks guys hope U all can help me

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since your numbers are 2 digits max you can try this approach.
First divide the number by **10** then for example if we divide **21** by **10** we get **2** and **some reminder** with **math.floor** we get rid of the reminder just **2** is left then we multiply **2** by **10** we get **20** that is the first part.
The second part just use % on the the number to get the reminder so for example **21 % 10** it would be **1**

```js
var numbers = [20, 21, 22];
var numberSeperator = function(number){
  return [Math.floor(number / 10) * 10, number % 10];
}

for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  console.log(numberSeperator(numbers[i]))
}
```